# Terraform hangs on Azure App Configuration

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm not sure why it hangs on

> azurerm_app_configuration_key.ai_connection_string: Still creating... [27m21s elapsed]

I assume that has something to do with dependencies but I'm not sure. New to terraform. Any ideas?

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.65.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  features {}
}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}-terraform-rg"
  location = var.location
}

# Application Insights
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "ai" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-gridbotapi-ai"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  application_type    = "web"
}

output "instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ai.instrumentation_key
  sensitive = true
}

output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ai.app_id
}

# Key Vault
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                        = "${var.name_prefix}-kv"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = true

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "Delete", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify", "GetRotationPolicy"]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "Set"]
  }
}

output "tenant_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
}

output "object_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ai_connection_string" {
  name         = "ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"
  value        = "InstrumentationKey=${azurerm_application_insights.ai.instrumentation_key};IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-4.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westeurope.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

# Azure App Configuration
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconfiguration" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-appconfiguration"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "ai_connection_string" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconfiguration.id
  key                    = "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"
  value                  = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.ai_connection_string.id})"
}
```

### Edit

> waiting for App Configuration Key "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString" read permission to be propagated: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Error, Exists, NotFound' (last state: 'Forbidden',
> │ timeout: 1m58.1932854s)

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.65.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  features {}
}

# Resource Group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "${var.name_prefix}-terraform-rg"
  location = var.location
}

# Application Insights
resource "azurerm_application_insights" "ai" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-gridbotapi-ai"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  application_type    = "web"
}

output "instrumentation_key" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ai.instrumentation_key
  sensitive = true
}

output "app_id" {
  value = azurerm_application_insights.ai.app_id
}

# Key Vault
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "kv" {
  name                        = "${var.name_prefix}-kv"
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = true

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions    = ["Get", "Create", "Delete", "List", "Restore", "Recover", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Purge", "Encrypt", "Decrypt", "Sign", "Verify", "GetRotationPolicy"]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "Set"]
  }
}

output "tenant_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
}

output "object_id" {
    value = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ai_connection_string" {
  name         = "ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"
  value        = azurerm_application_insights.ai.connection_string
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}

# Azure App Configuration
resource "azurerm_app_configuration" "appconf" {
  name                = "${var.name_prefix}-appconf"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  sku                 = "standard"
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "appconf_dataowner" {
  scope                = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  role_definition_name = "App Configuration Data Owner"
  principal_id         = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}

resource "azurerm_app_configuration_key" "ai_connection_string" {
  configuration_store_id = azurerm_app_configuration.appconf.id
  key                    = "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"
  value                  = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=${azurerm_key_vault_secret.ai_connection_string.id})"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_role_assignment.appconf_dataowner
  ]

  timeouts {
    create = "2m"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is an option to set a timeout: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_configuration_key#timeouts. Doing so should give you the information about the problem you are facing, but faster.

Comment: @MarkoE, thanks, good point! I didn't know that. waiting for App Configuration Key "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString" read permission to be propagated: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Error, Exists, NotFound' (last state: 'Forbidden', 
│ timeout: 1m59.4623519s)

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/A7evYv9.png it has Contributor role, so dunno what's wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign the **"App Configuration Data Owner"** role for the identity running Terraform to the scope of the App Configuration resource or any parent scope, as App Configuration Keys are provisioned using a Data Plane API, according to the provider documentation (I´ve validated it also):

*> **Note**:
App Configuration Keys are provisioned using a Data Plane API which requires the role App Configuration Data Owner on either the App Configuration or a parent scope (such as the Resource Group/Subscription). More information can be found in the Azure Documentation for App Configuration.*

Just a tip regarding your configuration: you can reference the connection_string of the App Insights directly rather than concatenate its values, as it is exported by the resource itself:

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ai_connection_string" {
 name         = "ApplicationInsightsConnectionString"
 value        = azurerm_application_insights.ai.connection_string
 key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great tip! I was trying to figure out how to not hardcode it. I tried what you said but getting:  `waiting for App Configuration Key "ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString" read permission to be propagated: timeout while waiting for state to become 'Error, Exists, NotFound' (last state: 'Forbidden', │ timeout: 1m58.1932854s)`. Any idea why?

Comment: Actually it worked right now, hmm. That's weird. Let me destroy the whole infra and re-apply the changes. Do you believe what I did is acceptable? I was going to move each service e.g. AI, KeyVault into their own folders

Comment: Yeah, actually this is optional, I believe that the more important is to define a standard and keep it for all your projects. You should create an output.tf file and move your outputs into it. It seems to already a have a separate variables.tf file to define your variables. The providers definition I normally put it into a versions.tf file ou in the main.tf file and then I create another file with a descriptive name regarding your project that will have the resources definitions.